# Freeing arr returns error malloc: *** error for object pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to write a function which takes 2 arrays and their size (both same size) and returns an array with each number from the first array appearing the amount of times in the same index in the second array. Example:  input: {2,5,3,7,8},{5,2,0,4,3},5 output: {2,2,2,2,2,5,5,7,7,7,7,8,8,8}

My current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* blowUpArray(int numArray[], int amountArray[], int size);
int* reallocateArr(int* arr, int currLogSize, int newSize);

int main() {
    int arr1[] = {2,5,3,7,8},arr2[] = {5,2,0,4,3}
    int* res;
    res = blowUpArray(arr1,arr2,5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        printf("%d ", res[i]);
    return 0;
}

int* blowUpArray(int numArray[], int amountArray[], int size)
{
    int i = 0,currSize = 0,j;
    int* blownUp;
    while (i < size)
    {
        blownUp = reallocateArr(numArray,currSize,amountArray[i]);
        for (j = currSize; j < currSize + amountArray[i]; j++)
        {
            blownUp[j] = numArray[i];
        }
        currSize = currSize + amountArray[i];
        i++;
    }
    return blownUp;
}

int* reallocateArr(int* arr, int currLogSize, int addedSize)
{
    int* newArr;
    int i;

    newArr = (int*)malloc((currLogSize + addedSize) * sizeof(int));

    if (newArr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < currLogSize; i++)
        newArr[i] = arr[i];

    free(arr);

    return newArr;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee644b6f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reallocateArr` function is freeing the `arr` parameter.  It is called like this:

```
reallocateArr(numArray,currSize,amountArray[i]);
```

Where `numArray` is a parameter to the function `blowUpArray` which is called like this:

```
res = blowUpArray(arr1,arr2,5);
```

Where `arr` is an array local to the `main` function.  Because this array was declared as a local variable, you can't pass it to `free`.

You probably wanted to pass `blownUp` to `reallocateArr`:

```
reallocateArr(blownUp,currSize,amountArray[i]);
```

You should also initialize this variable to `NULL`:

```
int* blownUp = NULL;
```

So you can safely pass it to `free` on the first iteration of the loop in `blowUpArray`.